# "Эрудированный специалист" — грамотно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость

Правильно ли будет сказать: "эрудированный специалист"?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, в жизни встречаются "эрудированные специалисты", но само **сочетание мне не кажется корректным, оно внутренне противоречиво.**

Специалист, по определению,  обладает профессиональными знаниями по определенной специальности, то есть это **ограниченный круг** знаний.

Эрудит же прежде всего имеет **широкий интеллектуальный кругозор**, его знания охватывают несколько областей. И это не просто знания, взятые из учебных пособий, а знания мировоззренческие, полученные путем осмысления различного рода информации.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эрудиция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Пример:** Он  умница, по-настоящему образованный человек, **эрудированный,** тонко разбирающийся в музыке и хорошо ее знающий.

Здесь указаны профессиональные достоинства человека (хороший специалист, тонко разбирается в музыке), но ум, образованность, эрудиция рассматриваются как отдельные личностные качества.

Comment: Вот нашел: нужен эрудированный специалист по издательскому делу. (http://profvibor.ru/pp/catalog/?SECTION_ID=148&ELEMENT_ID=2966) Тут эрудиция действительно нужна в рамках профессии. Нет противоречия

Comment: "Современный специалист по издательскому делу – это не только грамотный, эрудированный СПЕЦИАЛИСТ, в совершенстве обладающий знаниями по русскому языку и литературе, но и ЧЕЛОВЕК с прогрессивным сознанием, владеющий методами работы на рынке, изучающий спрос на издательскую продукцию".   О чем и я говорю: грамотный специалист в области русского языка и эрудированный человек в других областях. Просто у них  "эрудированный" немного не на месте (в однородных отношениях с "грамотным"). А если вы будете, к примеру, выбирать сантехника, то какого предпочтете, хорошего (грамотного) или эрудированного?

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина - невразумительное объяснение, Ссылка на "мне кажется" без пояснения причин - не принимается. Автор просто не понимает, что эрудированным может быть любой человек независимо от прочих качеств и достоинств.

Answer (score 2):

> Правильно ли будет сказать "Эрудированный специалист"?

Ну а почему бы и нет?

Из ответа Sibylla в этой теме:

> Специалист, по определению, обладает профессиональными знаниями по
>   определенной специальности, то есть это **ограниченный круг** знаний.

Пусть так. Но не стоит забывать о том, что круги-то бывают разного размера: кто-то ограничился тем, что получил на лекциях в институте (и стал после этого дипломированным **специалистом**), а у кого-то широта и  глубина познаний значительно выше…

Мне сочетание ***эрудированный специалист*** нисколько ухо не режет.  Так говорят.

Из поздравительной статьи  кафедры романской филологии Ленинградского госуниверситета, посвящённой 60-летию завкафедрой Александра Александровича Касаткина:

*А. А. Касаткин — **эрудированный специалист** в области романского и общего языкознания…*

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> (Филологические науки. № 3, 1979)

Comment: Я на это выражение тоже не обратила бы особого внимания, пока не задали этот вопрос. Кажется, Гете писал, что мы понимаем друг друга только потому, что говорим быстро и не вдумываемся в произносимые слова. Ну эрудированный, ну специалист, два хороших слова, почему бы им не объединиться. Но вот если поискать антоним к слову "специальный", то это будет слово  "общий". В вузах проходят общеобразовательные и специальные предметы, эти понятия всегда противопоставлялись друг другу. Но если сочетание ухо не режет, значит,  противоположности удачно соединились.

Answer (score 2):

*А если вы будете, к примеру, выбирать сантехника, то какого предпочтете, хорошего (грамотного) или эрудированного?*

***Эрудиция***  — начитанность, учёность, большие знания в какой-либо области науки и жизни или во многих областях науки и жизни.
(Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том IV, 1961)

"Хорошесть" = грамотность = "эрудированность": *эрудированный — **не есть только начитанный.***
**Специалист специалисту — рознь.**

Синонимы к слову «эрудированный» (а также близкие по смыслу слова и выражения):
*начитанный, книжный, образованный, **высокообразованный**, знающий, **грамотный**, сообразительный, умелый, сильный, способный, знаток, осведомленный, **учёный,** ходовой, сообразительный, практичный, искушённый, дошлый, **сведущий, компетентный**, понимающий, **много знающий.***

**эруди́рованный**
**1.** Обладающий эрудицией.
***Эрудированный специалист.*** Эрудированный студент. Журналистка деловита, энергична и эрудированна.
**2.** Связанный с эрудицией.
Эрудированные ответы.
[**Значение слова «эруди́рованный»**](http://rus-gos.spbu.ru/index.php/words/show/19288)

*Специалистам-логистикам необходимы обширные знания, знакомство с возможностями различных отраслей науки, информационными технологиями и технологиями перемещения в пространстве материальных объектов и информации, технологиями мотивации и стимулирования людей. **Только основательно** **эрудированные специалисты** могут уверенно полагаться на свою интуицию и логику при решении логистических задач.*
[**В. В. Волгин – экономист-международник, член Международной академии наук... (МАН ИПТ), "Эрудиция, интуиция, логика"**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%92_%D0%92_%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/1#p13)

М. *М. Лам – **образованный, эрудированный специалист,** а также требовательный и справедливый руководитель.

В моем представлении хороший тестировщик – **это любознательный, эрудированный** **специалист с гибким мышлением**, руководствующийся принципом «сделаю все, что может оказаться полезным».

А.Л. Юдин – известный в стране и за рубежом **квалифицированный и широко** **эрудированный специалист** в области цитологии и генетики одноклеточных организмов, общей генетики и клеточной биологии. Он автор более 120 научных публикаций...*
*Одним из первых руководителей хозяйства был Шульман А.И. - **эрудированный специалист в коннозаводстве.**

**Опытный и эрудированный специалист** в области обследования и лечения бесплодия.

В то время кафедру возглавлял Дмитрий Сергеевич Жевахов, **высоко эрудированный специалист, интеллигент с большой буквы.***

В моем понятии: ***эрудированный специалист —  это специалист особенный, не такой как все, незаурядный, уникальный, необыкновенный*** (врач; педагог; журналист; водитель-дальнобойщик, говорящий на пяти языках; гардеробщица с двумя высшими образованиями; уборщица — с институтом культуры "за плечами"...).

Answer (score 0):

БТС:
ЭРУДИЦИЯ, -и; ж. [лат. eruditio] Глубокие, **основательные познания в какой-л. области знания**, а также разносторонняя образованность. Обладать большой эрудицией. Литературная э.

Получается, что можно быть эрудитом в какой-то области — эрудированным специалистом. Вот пример из [книги](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=4_P7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&source=bl&ots=79dETGszus&sig=rYaC5HXDqB9HvmogyVOt4emysPM&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo0oPGmO_UAhXFIJoKHSKRAygQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&f=false) специалиста в области психологии, доктора мед. наук И. М. Фейгенберга

*Вы знаете. что хирург профессор Р. — очень знающий и **эрудированный специалист**,
внимательно следящий за всеми новинками литературы. 
Доктор же С. — гораздо **менее эрудированный специалист**, не следяший за новинками хирургический литературы*

Comment: "Мир изменился, и его главный лозунг - не эрудиция, а специализация" (Наполеон Хилл, американский психолог). Как видно из этого утверждения, эрудиция противопоставлена специализации, при этом автор очень высоко ценит специальные знания, которые должны постоянно совершенствоваться.  Но главное достоинство ученого - это умение мыслить.

Comment: Существует синтетическое и творческое мышление. Синтетическое мышление - это создание нового путем комбинирования известного,  а вот творческое мышление - это прорыв в неизвестное, и для этого нужно нечто большее, чем начитанность и осведомленность, нужно погружение в тему. Вот и остается вопрос : нужны ли нам  именно эрудированные специалисты и способны ли они к  новым научным открытиям.

Answer (score -2):

Проблем с сочетаемостью я тут не вижу Любой человек может быть эрудированным, в том числе и специалист.

Тут только одно может быть сомнение, да и то сильно по контексту. Если имеется в виду какой-то "узкий специалист" и под эрудированностью понимается его "знания" именно в его конкретной области, то "эрудированность" будет ошибочной характеристикой. надо сказать "подготовленный", "знающий". Но, повторяю, в этом и только в этом случае. Без этого контекста об ошибке говорит нельзя.

Владимир Солоухин. Третья охота (1967)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)

> «Прочитав ваши «Письма» о грибах в журнале «Наука и жизнь», я с
>   удивлением заметила, что такой эрудированный специалист, как вы,
>   оказался совершенно беспомощным при приготовлении сморчков!

(Пример из Нацкорпуса).
Там еще есть, но выбрал один, Солоухина в косноязычии заподозрить очень трудно.

Comment: Это слова не Солоухина, а одна из цитат под общим заголовком "Дополнение читателей о сморчках и строчках." http://mycoweb.narod.ru/fungi/Stories/Morchella_VS.html

Comment: @Alex_ander я понимаю, что это не прямая речь Солоухина, там же от лица женщины, что это меняет?!

Comment: То, что это случайный его читатель - можно только грамматические ошибки исправить, но не стиль или личную трактовку понятий.

Comment: @Alex_ander Мы говорим только о сочетаемости "специалиста" с "эрудированным". Никаких личных понятий. Спасибо.